# Integration between Bitbucket and Azure DevOps

Tags: azure, azure-devops, continuous-integration, bitbucket, webhooks

My requirement is I want to integrate my Bitbucket repo with the Azure DevOps CI server so that as soon as I push code in the bitbucket repo my pipeline should trigger in the Azure DevOps CI server for that I have created a webhook in the Bitbucket repo.

I have added the Azure DevOps CI server URL in the URL section and added secret in a secret section of the webhook of Bitbucket. the secret is personal access token generated in Azure DevOps Server.
But while creating a webhook I am getting

```
Resource not available for anonymous access. Client authentication required. - Azure DevOps server
```

Even though I have added a secret why it is giving client authentication required error? what could be the reason?

P.S. - There is a scarcity of documentation for integration between Bitbucket repo and Azure DevOps CI server

[image]

**Update** : I have already enabled continuous integration on the triggers tab as suggested by Vito Liu-MSFT in the answer but still my pipeline is not getting triggered automatically when I push my code to feature/POC branch in bitbucket.

[image]

Yml file is as follows

```
resources:
  repositories:
  - repository: myRepo
    type: externalgit
    name: 'myRepo' 
    endpoint: myrepo
    ref: feature/POC 

trigger:
  - feature/POC
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have finally created webhook from below URL by replacing values in {} braces. Now  i got 200 response in webhook

```
       https://{hostName}/{collectionName}/_apis/public/pipelines/webhooks/{projectName}/{buildDefinitionId}/{repositoryKey}?api-version=6.0-preview.1
```

Comment: how do you get the repository key?

Answer (score 1):

> I push code in the bitbucket repo my pipeline should trigger in the Azure DevOps CI server

We could create **service connection** in the Azure DevOps, create pipeline in the Azure DevOps and select Bitbucket Cloud as source, then select `Enable continuous integration` on the `Triggers` tab. We could refer to this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/bitbucket?view=azure-devops&tabs=classic) for more details.

**Update1**

Yes, We do not need Webhook in the Bitbucket if we enable continuous integration on the triggers tab. I have shared my test result, you could check the pic below.

[image]

**Update2**

According to the pic, it seems that you are using **Azure Repos Git** as the source instead of **Bitbucket Cloud**, note the source icon

[image]

**Update3**

Create yaml pipeline in the Azure DevOps, we need select Bitbucket Cloud as the code resource.

[image]

Then select Bitbucket repository, it will save the yaml file in the Bitbucket Repo instead of Azure DevOps repo, then we could configure the CI trigger.

[image]

I am using default yaml template do the test.

Note: we need update the field trigger, Azure DevOps has update the default branch to **main** instead of **master**

[image]

Note: If the yml file save in the Azure DevOps repo, it will not trigger the build if we push code in the Bitbucket repo.

Result:

[image]

Comment: Webhook is not needed if we enable continuous integration on the triggers tab?

Comment: Yes, you could check the update1 and then kindly share the result here.

Comment: I have followed procedure suggested by you but still my pipeline is no getting triggered automatically.

Comment: Hi @PawanPatil, please check the update2 and note the source icon, we should create service connection and then select Bitbucket Cloud as source in the pipeline.

Comment: Wait, you are using YAML build instead of classic editor, right?

Comment: yes i am using yml build. what is difference between yml file and classic editor? I have posted my yml file in question

Comment: I have shared the test steps in the update3, please check it and share the result here.

Comment: how to trigger pipeline if my yml file is in the azure repo and my rest of the code is in bitbucket repo and I push my changes to bitbucket repo

Comment: It seems that we cannot do this. If you do not want to save the Yaml file in the Bitbucket repo, create classic editor pipeline will better

Comment: finally i have created webhook.I will post in the answer

Comment: Hi @PawanPatil, You could kindly share your answer here and  accept it. So it could help other community members who get the same issues and we could archive this thread. Thanks. Have a nice day. :)

Comment: Hi @PawanPatil, Would you like to share your answers here and accept it? Thanks.

Comment: posted the answer

Answer (score 0):

Where is the BitBucket on-perm server hosted? Can you access the BitBucket on-premise repositories with the external internet? If it is, then the Hosted agents can also access them.

But if you cannot access the repositories from external internet, then the hosted agents will also cannot access the BitBucket on-premise repositories. So, you have to expose the BitBucket server on the internet.

Another workaround is deploying a private agent (self-hosted agent) on the BitBucket on-perm server or any other machine which located in the same network with the BitBucket on-perm server. Thus the private agent can access the BitBucket repositories...